# Rock scissors paper game in Solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, games

For a homework problem, I need to write a contract for a rock-paper-scissors game for two players who would deposit the same amount of money then the winner will get both deposits. I am new to Solidity and don't know where to start.

---

[image: here is the assignment]

Answer (score 2):

If the assignment is meant for people who are only starting their Solidity path and the assignment really is written as you said, I would argue that the assignment is a really bad one. Mostly because:

1) To do it right is actually quite complicated. Check out my other answer and @Tjaden Hess's comment on it.

2) To do it wrong leads to wrong kind of thinking.

There are many ways to do it wrong and it's really impossible to say which level of "wrongness" is expected of a "correct" answer.

Comment: im experiencing  it right now

Comment: From the question added in the edit, it looks like the assignment is looking for a commit-reveal protocol, which is the correct way to implement this. A 1-phase solution is simply incorrect

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for some study reasons.

If you need to do this for any serious reasons (for a company or so), you'd face serious issues with synchronization: if player A sends his transaction with Rock, player B can just check the transaction and send his transaction with Paper as he knows what player A played.

Nevertheless, for a basic idea you could use something like the following. Note that the concept of "Rock" is here represented as number 1 in variable `move`, "Paper" as number 2 and "Scissors" as number 3:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract RPS {

    uint256 previousMove;
    uint256 previousStake;
    address previousPlayer;

    function play(uint256 move) payable {

        // TODO: make sure stakes are the same

        if (previousMove == 0) {
            // If there is no move before this, make this the first move and Ethers stay in the contract
            previousMove = move;
            previousStake = msg.value;
            previousPlayer = msg.sender;
            return;
        }

        if (previousMove == 1) {
            if (move == 2) {
                // ...

                // if wins:
                msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);

                // if loses:
                previousPlayer.transfer(address(this).balance);
            }
        }
        // ...

    }
}
```

This is a very crude version but you'll hopefully get the point.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply ,  yeah it is for study reason so basically u say that palyer 2 is cheating ?

Comment: I'm not saying player 2 is cheating. I'm saying it would be trivial for player 2 to cheat.

Comment: ok i'm running the code in value box i input the number of ether but in play field what should input ?

Comment: move i know , but address?

Comment: I extended the example a bit now and removed the unneeded "player" variable.

Comment: Hi again , i hope you can bear my questions, you added a "previous player " term and it = msg.sender >>> i know this mean that it returns some kind of string but i havent entered anything ? could you explain ?                                                             another thing we have [ 0,1,2] so there are Rock paper and scissors ? in this order ? how did you specify them like that ?

Comment: because i have to deploy it to the course network in order for a classmate play with me so the output is not clear in Javascript run

Comment: As I said, the example is a crude one and in no way functional. You should really figure out the rest by yourself or ask a new question if there are some concepts that you are unfamiliar with. Anything from variable `msg` is retrieved from the transaction so user doesn't need to input those (such as address of the sender of the transaction). Also the order [1,2,3] is arbitrary - define it as you like.

Comment: yeah im trying to complete it , [ msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);] this line you put it in case of winning and losing , could you explain what it does?

Comment: You can avoid the cheating issue by doing a 2-phase game. Fist submit the hash of the move, with a salt, then reveal the move after both players have committed.

Comment: Hi i have a question i wrote the code for the whole game " hopefully correct" however i discovered that i cant execute the rest of the code cause it is still treats me as player1 although i input a modifer function for that

Comment: This contract is not publicly verifiable though.